# Ebook makes Apple Books app crash

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, ebook, calibre

I have a Word document which I convert to .epub using Calibre. To inspect the resulting ebook, I import the .epub file into the Apple Books app on desktop. This conveniently imports the book onto my iOS Apple Books app as well.

On desktop, Apple Books crashes frequently after opening the book. Sometimes it crashes within 10 seconds, sometimes within 15 minutes (I've never waited longer than 15 minutes to reproduce the issue). On mobile, Apple Books never crashes after opening the same file.

To be clear, when Apple Books 'crashes', it doesn't crash the entire program—just the book itself. It closes the reader and returns me to the bookshelf (which I leave open in the background). The book's custom cover art is replaced with a generic, programmatically created cover with a cloud icon in the top-right corner, and I can't reopen the book. Instead, it is shown as an available download with a forever loading spinner. On mobile, on the other hand, it continues to work just fine.

The issue persists if I use the [Publish Drive converter](https://converter.publishdrive.com) instead of Calibre. It also persists if I drastically reduce the Word document to a single page before conversion. It even persists if I copy the Word document's contents into a brand new Word document and then use the new document for conversion. I've tried removing all bookmarks from my Word document. I've tried removing the index. I've updated Calibre to the latest version. I've restarted my computer. Still no dice.

The only time I cannot reproduce the issue is if I use a Word document that's not only brand new but also contains brand-new text, or when I use a pre-existing ebook from my library.

At this point my best guess is that it's not an issue with Calibre, since Publish Drive results in the same bug. Maybe my Word file or even the text inside it is corrupted somehow, but I wouldn't know how to check for that.

How do I get this Word-to-epub conversion to work?

I use Word for Mac 16.46 and Calibre 5.25.0.

EDIT: Not even converting to a Pages document first and then converting to .epub from within Pages fixes it.

Comment: The problem is with the conversion software and with the text in your document (possibly pasted / converted from yet another format). That it does not occur with a new document and new text tells us something.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon “The problem is with the conversion software […]”: Shouldn’t having used three different types of conversion software rule out this possibility? Hard to believe they’d all have the exact same bug… “(possibly pasted / converted from yet another format)” no but the document was frequently sent back and forth between a Windows user and me.